# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome Very slow

Tags: 20.04

I have just upgraded to 20.04 without any issues, however, Gnome is painfully slow 2second delay with every action, apps take an age to open, terminal takes 2 sec to scroll through the history one item at a time.
Anyone else seen this and have any answers?

Comment: What are your system specs?

Comment: 3Ghz 8 core AMD, 32GB ram

Comment: 20.04 Gnome desktop suddenly became extremely slow on my high-end hardware with scads of RAM, disk, swap, etc. for no obvious reason (e.g. log files clear). With this and the random WiFi disconnects that now occur daily, I think 20.04 was not actually ready for release.

Comment: I have a 36 Core Xeon with 512GB of RAM and this is slow for me. WTF?? Seriously what is the point of this stupid window manager if it's so slow?

Answer (score 29):

**;tldr Avoid using the Fractional scaling and solve the scale of your high-dpi screen by reducing its resolution.**

I was dealing with a terribly slow GNOME desktop for a few days now (after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04). I do not use any GNOME extensions and I have turned off animations using Gnome Tweaks. I also installed `sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq` to set CPUs to `performance` instead of `powersafe`. I checked the BIOS settings to aim for the maximum performance when on AC. But nothing helped. All window movements were lagged, sluggish, movements were ~2s delayed. Mouse cursor was jumpy. It always took 1-2s to change a Firefox tab and scrolling was not at all smooth and freezing at random times for a while. YouTube videos were unwatchable, even scrolling through a terminal was slow! It was just unacceptable.

I have a reasonably powerful notebook so it just did not feel right:

- Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7gen 20QD
- CPU Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
- GPU Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
- RAM 16GB
- OS NAME Ubuntu 20.04.LTS
- GNOME Version 3.36.3
- Windowing system X11
- ThinkPad USB-C Gen2 Docking station
- 3 monitors (built-in 14" WQHD, external 24" and 22")

I made sure that I have:

- everything updated
- the newest kernel (5.4.0-40-generic)
- newest UEFI BIOS etc.

As it turns out, the problem was in the Fractional scaling the whole time. I know they write `May increase power usage, lower speed, or reduce display sharpness`, but damn this was not usable at all.

But I can not live without it, since my built-in display is WQHD (2560x1440) and when the Fractional scaling is off, both external monitors are OK, but everything on the built-in display is just tiny and unreadable. I tried switching to Wayland, it seemed promising for a while, until random freezes started occurring so I ditched the idea.

And then I realized I can just **lower the resolution on my built-in monitor <facepalm>**. The final solution was to turn off the Fractional scaling and reducing the resolution of the built-in monitor to FullHD. I sacrificed some sharpness, but the whole desktop is lightning fast now even with the animations and on powersave. I hope the Fractional scaling will get better at some point.

Comment: I have a similar issue but instead of fractional scaling I've just increased text size with `$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` (this one gets current value, should be 1.0 by default). Use `set` instead to e.g. 1.4.

Comment: I had played with it when I freshly installed it, had clicked the revert settings, but that was one option that hadn't reverted itself, just the scaling.

Comment: THANK YOU! You make my life sooooooo smooth!

Comment: Btw I had the same issue but I did not have fractional or any scaling enabled. I just had one screen at 4k and two at 1440p and it causes sluggishness in some cases. Reducing the 4k screen to 1440p resolved the issue for now.

Comment: My guess; This is not the solution people want, at first. Then they realize, like me, this is the only solution that properly works. Hope scaling gets better support in ubuntu soon.

Comment: I feel stupid, and grateful -- changing the resolution instead of using fractional scaling indeed fixed my problems, namely:  sluggishness of all input speed and flickering. Facepalm, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I have had same issues last two days. Everything was slow down and wifi connection was disconnecting periodically. if you have wifi problem, I suggest turn off wifi and plug in a lan cable before start.

try `sudo apt update` And `sudo apt upgrade` commands, then follow these instructions https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/ (Wouter De Coster's comment from Lynwode answer), then https://askubuntu.com/a/961460/934684 disable wifi powersave mode, then restart; now everything good for me.

maybe my answer might not meet the answer qualification. but because of my reputation I couldn't comment. I wanted to write them, maybe it works. because it's very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Looks like Nvidia driver issue. Re-installed the default and we off and running

Comment: You can give more details about how you reinstalled the default, as that may help new users.

Comment: install nvidia driver will make 20.04 can not login

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I had the same issue and followed these instructions: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

Comment: I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 including the proprietary drivers, but could not login as Liao mentions above.  After that I re-did the fresh install but without the proprietary drivers and instead using the nouveau driver, and ran into the same problem as OP where everything was very slow.  After that I simply installed nvidia-driver-390 using the link Wouter provided and everything worked.

Comment: Made no difference for me.

Comment: To install nvidia driver : sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440, although it did not make any improvement in may ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with a HP elitedesk 800 G6.

It turns out in my case the problem comes and goes depending on where I plug the monitor in. If I plug the monitor into the graphics card it's fine. If I plug the monitor into the motherboard it's unstably slow.

So if you are suffering from this issue check where your monitor is plugged in.