# Ubuntu / PopOS 21.04 - Screen blinking

Tags: graphics, display, screen, intel, 21.04

I just bought a Fusion Serie from PCSpecialist and I'm having screen issue when running Ubuntu (tested 20.04 and 21.04) or PopOS (tested 21.04)

- built-in screen display is blinking when the mouse cursor is moving within its display area using the touchpad or a mouse
- if I press the left button while moving the cursor the display does not blink
- when using an external monitor its display is fine, but not the integrated screen one (in duplicated or extended mode)
- I recorded the screen and the video is not showing the blinks (although the screen was blinking while recording)

What I tried:

- changing screens resolutions
- enabling / disabling PopOS HiDPI daemon
- use different kernels (from 5.11 to 5.14)

Here are the laptop specs:

- Chassis & Display: Fusion Studio Series : Écran large LED mat 14 pouces 90 Hz sRGB 95 % WQXGA (2880 x 1800)
- Processor (CPU): Processeur Quad Core Intel® Core® i7 11370H (3,3 GHz, 4,8 GHz Turbo)
- Memory (RAM): 16 Go Corsair 2933 MHz SODIMM DDR4 (2 x 8 Go)
- Graphics Card: Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics
- 1st M.2 SSD Drive: 500 Go SAMSUNG 970 EVO PLUS M.2, PCIe NVMe

And some commands outputs (from PopOS 21.04):

```
uname -r
5.11.0-7633-generic

inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
           Device-2: Chicony HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting
           unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1: 1440x900~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.1

sudo lshw -c video
*-display                
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=2880x1800 visual=truecolor xres=2880 yres=1800
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:153 memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Tongfang Hongkong Limited Iris Xe Graphics [1d05:1105]
```

Full probe of my system: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=9361e69812

I don't really know which potential fixes I should start with therefore any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

NOTE: I also have W10 installed along side PopOS and W10 is working fine.

Comment: Do you still have Ubuntu installed?  Ubuntu is [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic); PopOS is not on-topic. Please edit your question so that it is on-topic.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Your paste is from a non-Ubuntu system. Pop!_OS does not use Ubuntu kernels, and uses *testing* packages, where as only Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu with software from Ubuntu repositories only are on-topic here.  Your paste is not from a Ubuntu system.  You should provide specific details as to what you tried with Ubuntu & leave off off-topic detail (unless helpful), as Ubuntu LTS releases are available with two kernels stack choices (you didn't give any details of what you tried; 3 kernels are available for 20.04 but you list only 3rd party non-Ubuntu details skipping what is on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this problem on the exact same processor. It turned out that an Intel power-optimization feature has to be turned off via grub.

Add "i915.enable_psr=0" to the default GRUB command line in /etc/defaults/grub, so it reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
```

The flickering is gone after activating this GRUB.

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for the very late reply. I had no time trying more fixes so I sticked to W10 for a few months.

I just tried to disable PSR and so far it is fine. Thanks a lot!

For people no using grub, you need to use the following:

    `sudo echo "options i915 enable_psr=0" >> /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf`

    `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

    `reboot`

Again thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you. Same machine, same vendor and same specs. After trying so many updates and this simple workaround worked for me.

Enable fractional scaling and using 125% scaling.
At least stopped the screen flickering.

Found the solution here: [Cursor flickers on primary display when fractional scaling is enable for dual monitors on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234189/cursor-flickers-on-primary-display-when-fractional-scaling-is-enable-for-dual-mo)

Let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: I used this trick but resuming from suspend was still not working and after reboots sometime I had to set back those settings. Therefore I finally went with @holgerstrunk answer at the cost of some battery life.