# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS can't scale second display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, settings

I am running a laptop and second display setup:

Laptop: Dell inspiron 16 plus (3072 x 1920)
Display: AOC (2560 x 1440)

This setup was running fine until a couple days ago. Suddenly the display settings where different and changing them currently has not the desired effect. When I change the scaling of my laptop screen in the setting, both my laptop screen and second display are scaled (with the same factor) and visa versa. The odd thing is however that the changes are displayed in the settings menu, but not actually visible on the displays. I would like to scale my laptop to 200% and my display to 100%, can somebody help me?

I already did some research online, but all the solution I found where not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue to after a restart.

I "solved" this by (in `Settings > Display`)

- enabling `Fractional Scaling`
- on primary display use `Scale: 175%` (*)
- on secondary display use `Scale: 100%`

(*) Side note:
As I have high-resolution on primary display, I used to have `200%`, but that caused mouse flickering on primary display. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257030/296989) for reference.