# Custom fractional scaling in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display

I want to set fractional scaling to somewhere in between 100% and 125%. Is there a way to do it? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4uj6.png) are the options currently available in the settings.

Comment: No, there isn't and even the available options are still considered "experimental".

Comment: @ChanganAuto do you know if custom fractional scaling is currently supported in any Linux?

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question.  100% is too small and 125% is too big. I'd settle for a fixed value of, say 1115%, but being able to get other intermediate values would be nice.  I'm surprised that this behavior has gotten so little attention.

Comment: [Are you using X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355476/209677)? On it fractional scaling seems [an experimental feature](https://launchpad.net/~3v1n0/+archive/ubuntu/mutter-x11-fractional-scaling) (`gsettings get org.gnome.mutter experimental-features`). You might prefer to [play with resolutions instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257985/349837), or [try](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#Fractional_scaling) `xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.10x1.10` for 110%

Comment: Like others have said, fractional scaling is still something like an experimental feature. In my opinion, KDE has a much better implementation than the standard Ubuntu Desktop. You might want to give that a try if this is important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if not the same you are asking, depending on what you want to do, you may achieve acceptable results with the scaling factor for fonts in Gnome Tweaks.

[image]

I have often combined this with the available stepwise values of Fractional Scaling (and in rare cases, also the resolution) for a nice look.

Note: I have this Fractional Scaling, and I don't recall if that stemmed from attempts at getting intermediate values...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can't currently be done through the settings GUI but if you edit the file `~/.config/monitors.xml` and look for `<scale>`, you can set a custom value.

For example, `<scale>1.12</scale>` would be 112% scaling like Unity used to have.

Log out and back in again to see your changes.

NB as the settings GUI does not support custom values it will continue to say 100%.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 22.04, the scale just reverted to 100%